# Python pandas script to automate transposing rows to column then getting the average of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, mean, transpose

I have a csv file with a table of Elisa readings for lectins in triplicate with different concentration for each lectin and their OD values: so rows are the lectins and columns are the different concentration

Example table

| NA | Concentration 1 | Concentration 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lectin 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Lectin 1 | 1.5 | 2 |
| Lectin 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Lectin 2 | 2 | 3 |
| Lectin 2 | 2 | 3 |
| Lectin 2 | 2 | 3 |

What I would like is to transpose this so that concentrations are rows and lectins are columns and then get the average values for of the different concentration from each lectin. there are about 13 lectins in triplicate with 12 different concentrations. Can someone advice the script for this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby and apply mean() to get the expected result, then you can transpose the df if you want to express the data in that way...

```
import pandas as pd

df_grouped = df.groupby("NA").mean().T
df_grouped
```

Output:

| NA | Lectin 1 | Lectin 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Concentration 1 | 1,5 | 2 |
| Concentration 2 | 2 | 3 |